# Passing Variables in Makefile

Tags: makefile, docker-compose

I'm using a Makefile to run various docker-compose commands and I'm trying to capture the output of a script run on my local machine and pass that value to a Docker image.

```
start-service:
    VERSION=$(shell aws s3 ls s3://redact/downloads/1.2.3/) && \
    docker-compose -f ./compose/docker-compose.yml run \
    -e VERSION=$$(VERSION) \
    connect make run-service
```

When I run this I can see the variable being assigned but it still errors.  Why is the value not getting passed into the -e argument:

```
VERSION=1.2.3-build342 && \
    docker-compose -f ./compose/docker-compose.yml run --rm \
    -e VERSION?=$(VERSION) \
    connect make run-connect
/bin/sh: VERSION: command not found
```

Comment: Where did the `?` in your command output come from?  there's no `?=` in the makefile recipe you showed us?

Comment: I must have grabbed that from one of the several other failures I hit whilst beating my head against a wall. The answer below worked beautifully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing several different Bourne shell and Make syntaxes here.  The Make `$$(VERSION)` translates to shell `$(VERSION)`, which is command-substitution syntax; GNU Make `$(shell ...)` generally expands at the wrong time and isn't what you want here.

If you were writing this as an ordinary shell command it would look like

```sh
# Set VERSION using $(...) substitution syntax
# Refer to just plain $VERSION
VERSION=$(aws s3 ls s3://redact/downloads/1.2.3/) && ... \
-e VERSION=$VERSION ... \
```

So when you use this in a Make context, if none of the variables are Make variables (they get set and used in the same command), just double the `$` to `$$` not escape them.

```makefile
start-service:
        VERSION=$$(aws s3 ls s3://redact/downloads/1.2.3/) && \
        docker-compose -f ./compose/docker-compose.yml run \
        -e VERSION=$$VERSION \
        connect make run-service
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! I tried to slap together solutions from various sources and ended up in that state.